# Why do certain Appdata settings disappear after relogging a Roaming Profile?

Tags: windows, group-policy, roaming-profile

I'm running into a pretty frustrating situation. Our users running on Windows 7 & 10 are using certain third party applications on their computers like:

- Slack
- Dropbox
- Spotify
- Whatsapp

Every time the user is logged out and/or PC is restarted, these applications will show behaviour that makes me think their settings are not being remembered.

- Slack is gone from its installation folder in Appdata
- Dropbox has logged out the user from Dropbox
- Whatsapp is also gone from its local Appdata folder

Our users are running on Roaming Profiles aswell as the following Group Policies:

- Redirected roaming Appdata folder
- cache local copy of profile
- do not roam local settings with roaming profile

So I feel like all the Appdata settings required to keep these applications working after a relog are being cached locally and thus should keep working after relogging.

Could anyone shed some light on this issue? It is driving me nuts!

Comment: PC freezed ? I ask as the roaming save/roam the HKEY/Current User only

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yagmoth555. Nope, the PC did not freeze. This is after proper logoffs and/or shutdowns.

Comment: Sorry, by freezed I mean change blocked on it, with app like deepfreeze

Comment: Ah like that! No we don't use any kind of configuration/tools to restore settings (or block setting changes) each time a PC reboots.

Comment: Ok, as you use roaming I guess the user dont always log at the same pc, the  bug appear if you install an app, use it on pc  x and relog directly into pc x ?

Comment: Nope, it's the same PC! Which makes it even more confusing.

Comment: The timestamp on the roaming seem ok? to be sure its able to save back to the store. Test by placing a shortcut on the desktop in worst case and check if it come back after another login

Comment: Sorry for my late response, yagmoth555. I can confirm the roaming profile synchronizes well. It's the local appdata that is not being remembered.